# Is it possible to overide inline css and make inline css property not to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a component in html page as below

```
 <div style='right:2px;'>
 </div>
```

Is it possible to override the `right` property in `internal css` and make it not to do work.I mean the right property should not work.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `!important` to override it. For more details [**check these usages**](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

```css
div {
  right: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<div style='right:2px; position:absolute;'>
  hai
</div>
```